# NullPointerException on controller when testing in SpringBoot API - Mocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, mocking

I don't know why, but my code is giving me a nullPointerException error when I try to use test any of my methods from the controller using MVC. Here I put some parts of code:

My **controller**(first method only):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/companias")
public class ControllerAPI {


    @Autowired
    private final CompaniaServiceImpl companiaService;

    public ControllerAPI(CompaniaServiceImpl companiaService) {
        this.companiaService = companiaService;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping("/{companiaId}/{field_name}")
    public Map<String, List<Object>> getByField(
        @PathVariable("companiaId") Long companiaId,
        @PathVariable("field_name") String fieldName) {

        return companiaService.getCompaniaByfield(companiaId, fieldName);

    }
```

Here is my **Service** (the one I'm trying to mock):

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CompaniaServiceImpl implements CompaniaService {


    private final CompaniaRepository companiaRepository;
    private final DefaultGroupRepository defaultGroupRepository;
    private final OfficeRepository officeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CompaniaServiceImpl(CompaniaRepository companiaRepository, DefaultGroupRepository defaultGroupRepository, OfficeRepository officeRepository) {
        this.companiaRepository = companiaRepository;
        this.defaultGroupRepository = defaultGroupRepository;
        this.officeRepository = officeRepository;
    }


    public Map<String, List<Object>> getCompaniaByfield(Long companiaId, String fieldName) {

        if (companiaRepository.existsById(companiaId)) {
            Map<String, Function<Compania, Object>> mapCompania = Map.of(
                "name", Compania::getName,
                "dominio", Compania::getDominio,
                "altas", Compania::getAltas,
                "bajas", Compania::getBajas
            );

            Compania c = companiaRepository.findCompaniaById(companiaId);
            Function<Compania, Object> retriever = mapCompania.get(fieldName);


            return Collections.singletonMap("success", List.of(retriever.apply(c)));
        }
        else throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Compania con id (" + companiaId + ") no existe"
        );

    }
```

Here is my **controller Test**:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
class ControllerAPITest {

    String token = "xxx";

    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerAPI controllerAPI;

    private CompaniaServiceImpl companiaService = Mockito.mock(CompaniaServiceImpl.class);

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception{

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerAPI).build();
    }


    @Test
    void getByField() throws Exception {
        Map<String, List<Object>> response = Collections.singletonMap("success", List.of("nombre1"));
        Mockito.when(companiaService.getCompaniaByfield(1L,"name")).thenReturn(response);

        this.mockMvc.perform(
                get("/companias/{companiaId}/{field_name}", 1L, "name")
                    .header("authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.success[0]").isNotEmpty())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.success[0]").value("nombre1"));
    }
```

And the **NullPointerException error** that is giving me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at database.configuration.controller.ControllerAPITest.getByField(ControllerAPITest.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

It gives me this error in the line that says ***this.mockMvc.perform(*** I don't know why I'm not being able to mock my service. If you could help me, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: 1. Use interfacs, you defined those so use them (in your controller and test). 2. Why Spring Extension in your test you aren't using anything Spring related in there, either use it or ditch the extension. 3. Judging from your test code you are mixing also JUnit4 and JUnit5 which isn't going to help either.

Comment: @M.Deinum It still doesn't solve the error :C

Comment: The main cause is mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 that is trouble waiting to happen. If you didn't solve that it simply won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue in your test is that you are mixing JUnit 4 annotations and JUnit5 in a single test. The `@Before` is from JUnit4 so the setup is never being run, hence no dependencies or mocks will be created. Hence a `NullPointerException` as nothing is injected.

In your code you should use the `CompaniaService` interface instead of the `CompaniaServiceImpl`. You have defined an interface which you should use to your advantage.

Change your controller.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/companias")
public class ControllerAPI {


    private final CompaniaService companiaService;

    public ControllerAPI(CompaniaService companiaService) {
        this.companiaService = companiaService;
    }
```

You don't need the `@Autowired` on the field as injection is done through the constructor!.

Now for your test you can do a couple of things.

1. Replace `@Before` with `@BeforeEach` which is the JUnit5 annotation to mark the method. You don't need the `@ExtendsWith` and `@ContextConfiguration`.
2. Instead of the `@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)` use the `MockitoExtension`, use `@BeforeEach` but not to initialize the mocks.
3. Use `@WebMvcTest` and `@MockBean` and let Spring Boot handle the injection and mock creation for you.

### Use proper annotations

```java
class ControllerAPITest {

    String token = "xxx";

    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerAPI controllerAPI;

    @Mock
    private CompaniaService companiaService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws Exception{

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerAPI).build();
    }


   @Test
   void getByField() throws Exception {  ... }
```

### Use `MockitoExtension`

```java
@ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ControllerAPITest {

    String token = "xxx";

    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerAPI controllerAPI;

    @Mock
    private CompaniaService companiaService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws Exception{
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerAPI).build();
    }

   @Test
   void getByField() throws Exception {  ... }
```

### Use `@WebMvcTest`

```java
@WebMvcTest(ControllerAPI.class)
class ControllerAPITest {

    String token = "xxx";

    @MockBean
    private CompaniaService companiaService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


   @Test
   void getByField() throws Exception {  ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, but following your changes two things happens, with mockitoExtension it throws this: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException...  And with WebMvcTest it throws this: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: If it throws those exceptions you haven't told everything there needs to be told or your mocking isn't complete for the second one (if there are multiple calls one the service you need to mock all of them). Or you are still mixing junit dependencies in your test).

Comment: ooooh, you mean like the repositories? (my service uses 3...) Sorry for all of this, It's my first time testing an MVC app...

Comment: No as for your service you should use the interface as I told and also did in the code!.

Comment: Ok, sorry, thank you very much, ExtendWithMockitop works, I changed the Service to the interface in the controller but I forgot to change it also in the constructor of the Controller. My bad!! Thaks you very much!