# Spring Boot RestController Testclass doesn't instantiate Mocked Variables

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking

I'm trying to create a Unit Test for a RestController in Spring Boot.

The Controller looks something like this:

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/endpoint")
public class MyRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> findSomethingById(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam("param1")String param1) throws MyServiceException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.findSomethingById(id,param1));
}
```

And the Unit Test Class looks as follows:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isA;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyRestController.class)
public class MyRestControllerUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyService service;


    @Test
    public void testGetSomethingId() throws Exception {
        when(service.findSomethingById("1", "something")).thenReturn("found");
        mockMvc.perform(get("/endpoint/1").param("param1","something"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
                // some more Expects
    }
}
```

The issue is that both the `service` and the `mockMvc` Variables are null during the execution of the Test, but shouldn't be as they should get intantiated by Spring according to their Annotations according to my Understanding.

Looking for similair issues I found mostly issues where Junit4 and Junit5 got mixed togehter, which seems not to be my problem.
Sample question I found [NullPointerException on controller when testing in SpringBoot API - Mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256493/nullpointerexception-on-controller-when-testing-in-springboot-api-mocking)

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.4 as well as Java 11 and I added the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency to my pom.xml for the Test dependencies

Below is the StackTrace I get when executing the Test with my IDEA:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyRestControllerUnitTest.findSomethingById(Line of when() as service is null and so is mockMvc)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

MainClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApplication</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <start-class>org.main.MyApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.main.MyApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: it looks like inject issue, so check for annotations please and maybe try those -> `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc`

Comment: @muhammedozbilici
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) is as far as I understand it part of Junit4 which shouldn't be mixed with Junit5

Comment: can you exactly post the error message? I assume spring context fails to start?

Comment: @NullishByte I added the Stacktrace as requested

Comment: can you please pom.xml and also main class.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal ok i added pom.xml and mainClass

Comment: I found out the issue. Please read my answer to know about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming because of the `@Test` annotation. You are using this annotation from the `org.junit.Test` package that is part of Junit4. Other annotations used in the test case are part of Junit5. So this is conflicting. Please use `@Test` annotation from the `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` package and try again.

Also, remove this dependency from the `pom.xml`

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: thx, was so sure I had nothing from junit4 anymore but didnt check the packages where the annotations are coming from

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by Rohit Agarwal, if you run

```
./mvw dependency:tree
```

You shall see transitive dependencies added by the spring-boot-test

```
 \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test autoconfigure:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.22.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test <------------- Note this
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
```

JUnit 5 added by spring-boot-test as a transitive dependency as shown above.
Since Springboot 2.4 Junit4 Vintage engine is removed.
Hence you should use the Junit5 Test annotation org.junit.jupiter.api.Test